# Download complex 3D JS/Canvas webpage for offline

Tags: web-scraping, offlineapps, offline-mode, offline-browsing

I'm attempting to download a truly offline version of this interactive 3D model of a home, as seen on this webpage: https://my.matterport.com/show/?m=bDbFD5mSEb5&play=1&lang=en

Because it loads dynamically, all the basic offline downloaders won't work.

I'm wondering if there's a way to extract a browser's cache, after all the page's content has downloaded? But all modern browsers seem to cache in strange encrypted DB files, and it's not easy to convert that into basic HTML/CSS/JS.

Is there a more sophisticated tool to extract a dynamic website? Ideally I'd end up with just pure HTML, CSS, and JS, as it's only an HTML5 webpage that loads images onto a canvas. Definitely possible in theory.